# How do the maximum rates of calcium pumping compare between the calcium ATPases SERCA and PMCA

Tags: cell-biology, literature, cell-signaling, homeostasis, calcium

Two important [Calcium ATPases](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calcium_ATPase) found within cells are the Sarcoplasmic reticulum Ca2+ ATPase (SERCA) and the Plasma membrane Ca2+ ATPase (PMCA). Both use ATP to help maintain resting calcium concentrations within cells as well as play important roles in calcium signaling.

How similar are these two calcium pumps? More specifically, **how do their maximum pumping capacities compare to each other?** I would assume that just because they are both calcium ATPases it does not mean they are similar in all properties. For example, the Wikipedia page linked above even mentions how

> The endoplasmic reticulum calcium pump...[is] inhibited by the tumor-promoting agent thapsigargin, which does not affect the plasma membrane calcium pumps.

Have any studies been done that compares the pumping capacities of these calcium ATPases? Or maybe is there a way to determine it based on their structure, roles, etc.?

Comment: I am not sure why this is being voted to be closed as a homework question. Can the close voter give pointers?

Comment: I didn't vote to close, but the rationale is likely as follows. Posters are expected to show that they have thoroughly researched a question before posting — ["Tell us what you found and why it didn’t meet your needs"](https://biology.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). This is not my field, but faced with this problem I would search for reviews of calcium ATPases — general and specific — using, say Google Scholar. Just restricting yourself to a very short Wikipedia article is hardly enough.

Comment: Thanks @David, will do!